# Is there a limit to the file size you can upload with GWT FormPanel and FileUpload?

Tags: java, file-upload, gwt

I recall seeing somewhere that there was a limit of 10MB upload in GWT when using `FormPanel` and `FileUpload`, but I can't seem to find any reference to a limit now. Is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reasonable limit* on the client side (or in GWT) of a `<input type=file>`. That said, it is quite likely that your server has a limit on the size of an upload, so be sure to configure whatever server (and optionally any reverse proxy in use) to use a high enough limit.

* technically, it appears there is a limit - the file cannot be larger than `2^64` bytes (about 18 million terabytes), at least according to MDN.